# Can the increment in Manipulate, Table, Range, etc. be subject to an If statement?

Tags: manipulate

In this demonstration I'm working on, I would like to plot a piecewise function with the tangent line to the function at a point that is determined by `c` in the code below.

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x, x < 0}, {x^2, x >= 0}}];
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{-1, x < 0}, {2 x, x > 0}}];
Manipulate[
  Plot[{f[x], f[c] + g[c] (x - c)}, {x, -3, 3}, Epilog -> Point[{c,f[c]}]],
{c, Range[-2, 2, .025], ControlType -> Slider}]
```

Is there some way to restrict the increment `c` so that when it's negative, the increment size is the default size, whereas when it's positive, the increment size is something a bit smaller? I'm trying to make it easier to see that the derivative from the right approaches $0$. I'm not sure how to properly use an `If` command to this end.

Comment: You can join two ranges together: `Join[Range[-2, 0, 0.025],Range[0.01, 2, 0.01]]`. But you can't use `If`.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for the tip, I had a feeling I was being too hopeful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this: Modify the `If` statement in the second argument of dynamics as you like. I set it now to jump by `0.2` if `c<0` and jump by `0.01` if `c>0` but you can change this.

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x, x < 0}, {x^2, x >= 0}}];
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{-1, x < 0}, {2 x, x > 0}}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], f[c] + g[c] (x - c)}, {x, -3, 3},
  Epilog -> Point[{c, f[c]}], ImagePadding -> 10, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}
  ],
 Grid[{{Manipulator[
     Dynamic[c, {c = #; If[c < 0, incr = 0.2, incr = 0.01]} &],
     {-2, 2, Dynamic@incr}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[c]}}],

 {{c, .1}, None},
 {{incr, .025}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code might get simplified by replacing the `Grid` part with something like `Row[{Slider[Dynamic@c, {-2, 2, Dynamic@If[Dynamic@c < 0, 0.2, 0.01]}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"]}]`. This avoids introducing `incr` as another variable and having a `Function` as the second argument of `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

One can make `c` and a `stepsize` with an `If` statement [interdependent controls of the `Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) without showing `stepsize`. However, this only works after making the `If` statement `Dynamic`.

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{-x, x < 0}, {x^2, x >= 0}}];
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{-1, x < 0}, {2 x, x > 0}}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x], f[c] + g[c] (x - c)}, {x, -3, 3}, Epilog -> Point[{c, f[c]}]], 
 {{stepsize, Dynamic@If[c < 0, .2, .01]}, None}, 
 {c, -2, 2, stepsize, ControlType -> Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

> [image: Output]